# Proving $R[Y_1, \ldots, Y_r]_{P}$ is integrally closed (trying to prove $\mathbb{P}^r_R$ is normal)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain with algebraically closed fraction field. 
Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R[Y_1, \ldots, Y_r]$. Then it follows that 
$R[Y_1, \ldots, Y_r]_{P}$ is an integral domain. I would like to prove that 
$R[Y_1, \ldots, Y_r]_{P}$ is integrally closed in its fraction field. Any explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit. I am asking this question because I wanted to prove that $\mathbb{P}^r_R$ is a normal scheme when $R$ is a valuation ring with an algebraically closed fraction field.

Comment: If $R$ is a valuation ring then it is integrally closed, then so is any polynomial ring over $R$, and its localizations as well.

Comment: @user26857 that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such?

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki answer recording the discussion from the comments, in order that this question might be marked as answered (once this post is upvoted or accepted).

> If $R$ is a valuation ring then it is integrally closed, then so is any polynomial ring over $R$, and its localizations as well. – **user26857**